# Java HashMap<String, String> has LinkedHashMap in value

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have a strange issue with a `HashMap` and not sure how to access the value. I have a `HashMap` returned to me from an API that is suppose to be `HashMap<String, String>`. One of the values is actually a `LinkedHashMap`. I've tried casting it, but since it is a `HashMap` that is `<String, String>` it's giving me an error that it's not possible. Is there anyway to get a `LinkedHashMap` value out of a `HashMap` that is `<String, String>`?

I have tried this with no luck: `((HashMap)userInfo.get("key")).get("key");`

```
     Could not complete request <java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String>java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

This is really ugly looking, but I was actually able to get it out of the HashMap with this:

```
(HashMap) ((HashMap)((HashMap)userInfo).get("picture")).get("data");
```

Thanks to Jeroen for sending me down the right path.

Comment: You need to provide more code and the error you get, otherwise your question isn't very clear.

Comment: LinkedHashMap is a subclass of HashMap, so why not just use the LinkedHashMap as a HashMap?

Comment: If your library is returning a raw HashMap without generics, it's probably very old and hard to work with. Look for something better.

Comment: Why do you want to cast it? You can call `get` on a `LinkedHashMap` just the same...

Comment: @Matthijs, it is using Generics and the problem is it is a HashMap<String, String>  so casting the value to a HashMap is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, but the issue is to get a LinkedHashMap out of a HashMap that is using generics <String, String>.

Comment: You can't put a LinkedHashMap as a value in a `HashMap<String,String>`. It shouldn't be possible, unless the library was using a raw type without generics.

Comment: Thats what I thought Matthijs, but I know it is a HashMap<String, String>. I believe the ObjectMapper for Jackson is creating that hashmap

Comment: Lol let the down votes begin, its a solution and I did say it is an ugly one. but thats what the API has handed me for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets placement.

Try

```
(((HashMap)userInfo).get("key")).get("key");
```

You have to cast before you use `.get()` (assuming your attempt is actually valid and it is just a matter of brackets).

Comment: Does not work, complains about casting since the HashMap this is working on is <String, String>

Comment: Ok I took it one step further and this actually works... even though it is pretty ugly: (HashMap) ((HashMap)((HashMap)userInfo).get("picture")).get("data");

Comment: I'll give you the answer since you sent me down the right path :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert typed map first to untyped map and then check type of each value. [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface is implemented by [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) classes so you'll most likely want to use it instead of more specific types.

```
HashMap<String, String> typedMap = ...
Map untypedMap = (Map) typedMap;
Object mapValue = untypedMap.get("key");

if(mapValue instanceof Map) {
  // handle as Map
}

if(mapValue instanceof String) {
  // handle as String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `LinkedHashMap` and you cast it to a `HashMap` you will have probelms.

You could instead treat it as a `Map`:

```
Map m = userInfo.get("key");
```

Comment: Really? [LinkedHashMap extends HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)!

Comment: Not sure how it would be confusing, in the title and various places it shows it is using generics <String, String> so return value is going to be a string.